# Promise that returns second promise result if first fails

Tags: javascript, promise, bluebird

I would like to return the value of a second promise if the first (value in cache) fails.

I have the following code, but resolve is not defined.

```
exports.getConfig = function (a, r) {
  return new Promise(resolve, reject)    {
    getConfigFromCache(a, r)
        .catch(function(e){
            getRouteConfigFromWeb(a, r)
        }).then(function(result) {
            //return value of the promise that was called
            resolve(result)
        })
  }
};
```

Assume that both getConfigFromCache and getRouteConfigFromWeb return promises correctly.

Is there a way to accomplish this, or am I thinking through it incorrectly?

Comment: you... never called resolve or reject..

Comment: thanks for pointing that out. I still have the same issue when calling resolve(result)

Comment: try caching `resolve`. `var _resolve = resolve;` or something similar before you enter `getConfig`

Comment: is the `.then()` supposed to be returning the result of either `getConfigFromCache` _or_ ``getRouteConfigFromWeb` regardless of which is used?

Comment: Alnitak, that is correct.

Comment: Avoid the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572)! Just `return` the promises.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't need to create a new `Promise` at all:

```
exports.getConfig = function (a, r) {
    var cache = getConfigFromCache(a, r);
    return cache.catch(function(e) {
        return getRouteConfigFromWeb(a, r);  // NB: return *essential*
    });
}
```

If the `getConfigFromCache()` call succeeds, the resulting resolved Promise should skip through the `.catch` and get returned directly.

If the cache call fails, the Promise returned from `getRouteConfigFromWeb()` is returned instead.

I note also that the very first line of your question actually gives the solution: *"I would like to return the value of a second promise if the first (value in cache) fails."* - you never actually put a `return` in the `.catch` block!

Comment: That is correct. The promise was passed through after all.

Comment: @user1886721 the key thing you were missing in your original code was the `return` inside the `.catch` block.  Without it, the Promise chain is broken.